# Jquery :first-line for IE8

Tags: jquery

I have a need to wrap the first line of the following sentences inside :

```
<span class="span">This is the first line <br> this should be the second line</span>
<span class="span">This is another first line <br> this should be another second line</span>
```

**Using jquery:**

```
$('.span:first-line').wrap('<em></em>');
```

I expected the result:

```
<span class="span"><em>This is the first line </em><br> this should be the second line</span>
```

**The CSS:**

```
.span {
    display:block;
    white-space:pre;
}
```

But no matter what IE do not seem to recognize it.

Looping through each resulting unexpected:

```
$('.span:first-line').each(function() {
    $(this).wrap('<em></em>');
});
```

**Bad Result:**

```
<em><span class="span">.................</span></em>
```

**Also:**

```
$('.span').each(function() {
    $(this).filter(':first-line').wrap('<em></em>');
});
```

Does anyone know other way to wrap the first line broken by a line break (`<br>`) whitespace to make it work for IE8?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".span").each(function(){
   var split = $(this).html().split(/<br.*?>/gi);
   split[0] = "<em>" + split[0] + "</em>";
   $(this).html(split.join("<br>"));
});
```

Updated to use regex instead of `<br>` now also `<br />` can be used to split.

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yZ2Se/1/

Comment: It works fine for other browsers, but not IE8. The result is the em wraps the entire sentence inside the span. Thanks

Comment: My, I sniff around the codes, and changed <br> to <BR> uppercase, and voila! Can you help to make BR uppercase optional, just in case its Windows specific, and not work at linux? I meant possible to put <br > and <BR> as options?

Comment: IE8 changes all tags to uppercase by default. I've added the Caseinsensitive to the regex. It should be working now in all browsers. It's the `i` behind the `/gi`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works beautifully. Thank you thank you. May all good things happen to you always.

Answer (score 1):

```
var val = $('.span').eq(0).val();

var splitted = val.split('<br>');
var newtext = '<em>'+splitted +'</em><br></br>'+splitted[1];

$('.span').eq(0).html(newtext);
```

Comment: He doesn't wanna wrap the first `.span`, but the first line of the `.span`.

Comment: I should not hardcode the content of the sentences, I am afraid, Thanks